# Why Quokka OpenSSL configuration error shown after install postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-code, openssl, vscode-extensions, quokka.js

I installed Quokka (A Visual Studio Code Extension) in windows. But after launching it in the current javascript file, it gives me some error message (below). After tried, I found that it's happening because of postgreSQL. I don't know why, What is the connection between Quokka and PostgreSQL (It does not make sense to me).

But it works fine after uninstalling PostgreSQL, Again I intalled it and doesn't work.

Quokka OpenSSL configuration error:

```
E4180000:error:80000002:system library:BIO_new_file:No such file or directory:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:67:calling fopen(C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\psqlODBC\etc\openssl.cnf, rb) 
E4180000:error:10000080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:75: 
E4180000:error:07000072:configuration file routines:def_load:no such file:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\conf\conf_def.c:179:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a empty file named `openssl.cnf` in `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\psqlODBC\etc\` this directory.

It resolve my problem after creating this empty configuration file in PostgreSQL ODBC.

Comment: I have had the same issue but using `git commit`. This solution worked fine for me as well.